# Maintain screen position always centered on cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension for VSCode where the editor screen is always centered on the cursor. There are other extensions that add a command to center the screen onto the cursor, but you have to press the command to activate it.

Currently the only way I've found to implement this is to rewrite the cursorUp, cursorDown, enter, pageUp, pageDown -- any command that moves the cursor up and down basically, and then use the "revealLine" command with the cursor line position and with the "at" attribute as "center".

Is there a better way? Reimplementing the default editor commands seems very inefficient.

Here's what I've got currently:

```js
"use strict";
import * as vscode from "vscode";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable1 = vscode.commands.registerCommand("cursorUp",() => {
            centralizar();
            vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove", {
                to: "up",
            });
        }
    );

    let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand("cursorDown",() => {
            centralizar();
            vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove", {
                to: "down",
            });
        }
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable1);
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable2);
}

function centralizar() {
    let currentLineNumber = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.start.line;
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("revealLine", {
        lineNumber: currentLineNumber,
        at: "center"
    });
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Comment: As Mark mentioned below, using `editor.cursorSurroundingLines` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you can utilize the new (v1.38) command `editor.cursorSurroundingLines`.  See [scrollOff release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_38.md#cursor-surrounding-lines-scrolloff).

[image: scrollOff demo]

It takes a number, but if you can get the number of visible lines in an editor window, then set `editor.cursorSurroundingLines` to the appropriate midpoint that may work.  It seems you would not have to listen for scroll events.  But would have to update the value if the editor window was resized.

Comment: You can set the number to a very high value (I use 500) and it keeps it in the center.

Comment: I find this to be extremely annoying, however, there is no reason for creating a solution when you can just do this. I don't know why there are other answers after this one, as the answers either add repeated information or deprecated information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Typewriter Auto-scroll VSCode Extension

Answer (score 0):

The [Scrolloff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tickleforce.scrolloff) extension implements this functionality when its "alwaysCenter" option is enabled.  It works by listening to [window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window), which fires when the cursor moves.

Comment: FYI: The addon has now been deprecrated in favor of @Mark's solution.

Comment: There is no need to use the scroll of extension, when the scroll of setting is available out of the box